# Get latest solution file or solution folder (complex dependencies )?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I have seen most of the time how developers in order to work on a solution, right click on solution folder in source control, select "Get Latest" and... have tons of problems: solution's projects reference other projects from other solutions, missing references, etc...

Here is the simulated example of something similar we have at work...
[image]

Now, imagine you have to work on TicketsSolution, specifically - fix some bugs, make changes with TicketsSolution's Web project. Usually developers right click on TicketsSolution's folder in TFS/VSS (whatever) and select "Get Latest"... and the above mentioned problems hit them right in the face.

Turns out, TicketsSolution also includes such projects as

Common.Solution1.Project1, which may have a reference to Common.Solution2.Project1

Common.Solution1.Project2

WCFServicesLibrary project, which may have a reference to SQLServerProxy project

also, some external 3rd patry DLLs that have been missing or placed somewhere under ROOT but outside the TicketsSolution folder...

In this scenario when you Get Latest for just TicketsSolution folder all those references will be missing,

**so it seems the only reasonable way** to **Get Latest** would be right-clicking on JUST the solution file, such as TicketsSolution.sln and getting latest of that file only. Then, opening that TicketsSolution.sln file in Visual Studio would hopefully :) reconstruct all the tree nodes within and beyond the solution folder required by the solution.

Even in this approach references for external DLL libabries will be missed, because VS knows how to reconstruct the folder-tree, but it doesn't include DLLs referenced outside of TicketsSolution folder.

But 90% of developers get latest of the solution folder and having tons of problems.

So, my question is - in this scenario, whould it be correct to include external projects in TicketsSolution solution, or it would be more reasonable to add "lib" folder under TicketsSolution folder and drop the dlls of all those external dependent projects in it, and then, reference them from the solution's projects, instead of reconstruction the entire folder tree with all the dependent projects from upper levels (that may and probably will have their own dependencies and reference problems) ??

Comment: Never open another solutions project within your solution. This is very bad practice and should be avoided. Treat each solution as an application and anything outside as a binary dependancy.

Comment: @MrHinsh, totally agree. The problem is that it was already in that state in the company I joined. And all those external projects, outside of this solution are also referenced by other project in the same way, they are like "common" to several solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Lib folder makes life simpler but introduces other issues in you build hierarchy.
Plus you have to store your libraries in source control which to some people is a no no.

I use a local NuGet feed.

I think the simplest answer to your question though, is to create a .bat file, write the check out calls for the folder s you need to check out for a solution, store in the solution root folder on TFS.

Get the devs to click the bat file to get latest on all of the files for the solution.

Comment: This is the correct and only solution to this issue. Package your dependencies as a nuget package and the other solutions consume it

Comment: @MrHinsh, yes, I agree, it's just I can't make my rules how to organize their TFS storage, it's massive, and I am here on a contract :) Besides they are "a little" behind for using Nuget :) I could've suggested all those referenced external projects compile into DLLs and put those DLLs into Lib folder inside the solution, and remove those external projects from this solution completely, leaving only projects that are part of the solution (inside solution's folder).